# How to disable/clear the rate limiter in a Laravel app (SendPortal)

Tags: laravel

I am trying to create an app to integrate with the SendPortal API, but I accidentally created an infinite loop and hit the rate limit. I can't seem to clear it or bypass it. I have tried changing the rate limit as suggested in the docs (https://sendportal.io/docs/v2/api/introduction#throttling), but it doesn't seem to have an effect. I have also tried `php artisan cache:clear` which I found elsewhere. Whatever I try, the API returns the page “429 | too many requests” I appear to be permanently locked out.

Comment: Maybe try to set the limit to a very high value or disable it for testings sake?

Comment: I tried it according to their instructions, but it didn't make any difference. I have ended up managing to edit the app/Http/Kernel.php file, but ideally, I'd rather not have to alter the core files to achieve this.

Comment: Editing those files is encouraged.